# repquota displays wrong data

Tags: linux, debian-wheezy, quota

Repquota seems not give correct number of block used, but only for user with assigned limits (30MB/50MB):

```
# repquota -s /skole/tjener/home0

*** Report for user quotas on device /dev/mapper/vg_system-skole+tjener+home0
Block grace time: 7days; Inode grace time: 7days
                    Space limits                File limits
User            used    soft    hard  grace    used  soft  hard  grace
----------------------------------------------------------------------
root      --    216K      0K      0K             48     0     0       
luca      --    531M      0K      0K           2757     0     0       
mario     +-    117M  30720K  51200K  6days    1962     0     0
```

If I do:

```
# du -sh /skole/tjener/home0/mario
56k
```

Instead for the user still without limits it is correct:

```
# du -sh /skole/tjener/home0/luca
531M
```

The entry in /etc/fstab is (all on a single line):

```
/dev/mapper/vg_system-skole+tjener+home0 /skole/tjener/home0    ext4     
nosuid,usrjquota=aquota.user,grpjquota=aquota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0  0   2
```

If I try to write some bytes in mario's home:

```
$ echo abcde > test.txt
```

I get:

```
dm-6: write failed, user block limit reached.
```

How I can fix this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just created a new user and repquota says that he has already used: 1595 inodes/54384 blocks

Answer (score 0):

I got a hint just on past answer here on Serverfault. I launched the following command:

```
find /skole/tjener/home0 -type f -user mario -print0 | du -ch --files0-from=- > files.txt
```

The cat of files.txt says:

```
115M    total
```

It's substantially the same value reported by repquota